# SQL CE: Top 1, if null then display 0

Tags: c#, sql-server, razor, sql-server-ce

So I have this kind of logic where `@1` in the query is `i` from the `for loop`

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {

    var getPR = "SELECT top 1 kg, rep, date FROM Test WHERE exerVariName = @0 AND rep = @1 order by kg desc"; 

    foreach (var c in query stuff) {
        // Display both results and 0 if no result
    }
}
```

So the database is setup in such a way that a kilogram value is entered (kg) along with a number of sets and reps as well as a name of the exercise and a date. The query will look though each exercise name, and see where the highest kilogram is for each rep between 1-12, so for exercise number one, check highest kilogram for rep 1, then 2 and so on, then next exercise and from 1-12, however, there isn't always a result that is matched if for example a certain exercise is not in the database with 5 repetitions set to it, so it would jump that and go to 6 and check again.

What I would like is that if there is no match from the database, set `c.kg` to `0` in the `foreach` so that there is still a value there, because I want to set up a html table with 12 rows and I want something in all of them, can this be done?

Using razor (cshtml), not MVC, and SQL server compact edition.

My code:

```
<table class="prTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Exercise</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>
            <th>8</th>
            <th>9</th>
            <th>10</th>
            <th>11</th>
            <th>12</th>
        </tr>
    <!-- Loops out all the different exercise names for deadlifts -->
    @foreach (var d in db.Query(getVariD))
    {
        <tr class="prTableRow">

            <td class="prExerVariNameTD">@d.exerVariName</td>
            @* Gives me a result from each rep range, var i goes from 1 up to choosen rep, and puts
                that into the sql string to get each rep range. *@
            @for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                //Selects the row with the highest weight from each exercise AND from each rep range
                //up to choosen value in the for loop.
                var getPR = "SELECT top 1 kg, rep, date FROM Test WHERE exerVariName = @0 AND rep = @1 order by kg desc";
                //Loops out the database values.
                foreach (var c in db.Query(getPR, d.exerVariName, i))
                {

                    DateTime Date = c.date;
                    var finalDate = "- " + Date.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");
                    var weight = c.kg + "kg";
                    var rep = "x " + c.rep;

                    <td class="prTableCell" title="@finalDate">@weight</td>
                }
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are many things wrong with this. You dont set parameter variables. You dont show any db/query code. What mean `both` results?  Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: the query code it right there mate, but I'll update my question a bit then!

Comment: does it make more sense now? @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: The problem make sense. But not sure where you are having issues. That code would never run because have many pieces missing. So either you dont know how create a basic db connection or you dont know how express the issue. For the first you should read a tutorial. For the second you should write a more complete code and tell us what is the specific issue.

Comment: ye thats what I thought really, that it would never run, but I'm wondering if somehow i can still set a 0 value to those non existing lines. Ill include my real code, just thought this would be easier to read. @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: Now is much better. Can you show us some sample db and how would you like the final result to be? Doesnt make sense you do a query for each rep. You should bring all the rep for each exercise at once

Comment: Is this SQL Server or SQL Server Compact ???

Comment: @ErikEJ SQL Server Compact Edition

Answer (score 2):

Using `row_number()` you can get the bigger kg for each rep. I think your query should be:

```
SELECT kg, rep, date
FROM (
     SELECT kg, rep, date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rep
                               ORDER BY kg DESC) as rn
     FROM Test 
     WHERE exerVariName = @0
     ) as T
WHERE T.rn = 1
```

Now if you want have 12 result for each exercise you need to provide a base table

```
SELECT base.rep, 
       COALESCE (res.kg, 0) as kg,
       COALESCE (res.date, '') as date

FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), 
             (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
     ) as base(rep)
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT kg, rep, date
       FROM (
            SELECT kg, rep, date,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rep
                                      ORDER BY kg DESC) as rn
            FROM Test 
            WHERE exerVariName = @0
            ) as T
       WHERE T.rn = 1
       ) res
  ON base.rep = res.rep
ORDER BY base.rep
```

Test each query separated so you understand what bring. And I think you can handle the final display just looping for all 12 results.

**EDIT** for SQL CE

```
SELECT base.rep, 
       COALESCE (res.kg, 0) as kg,
       COALESCE (res.date, '') as date

FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), 
             (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
     ) as base(rep)
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT T1.rep, T1.kg, T1.date
       FROM Test T1
       JOIN ( SELECT exerVariName, rep, max(kg) as kg
              FROM  Test 
              GROUP BY exerVariName, rep
            ) as T
         ON T1.rep = T.rep
        AND T1.kg = T.kg
        AND T1.exerVariName = T.exerVariName
       WHERE exerVariName = @0
         -- This is in case you can have duplicate kg for same rep.
         -- select the latest date
         AND NOT EXIST ( SELECT 1 FROM 
                         FROM  Test T2
                         WHERE T2.exerVariName = T1.exerVariName    
                           AND T2.rep = T1.rep 
                           AND T2.kg = T1.kg
                           AND T2.date > T1.date ) 
       ) res
  ON base.rep = res.rep
ORDER BY base.rep
```

Comment: the first code gave me error on `over` and the second one on `COALESCE` :/

Comment: can you have the same Kg / Rep in different dates? If so which date do you show?  the first, the last?

Comment: @ErikEJ I add another version for SQL Compact.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks

Comment: Still gives me error on `There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = COALESCE ]` And yes, there can be the same kg/rep on different dates, but which one to choose doesnt really matter! @JuanCarlosOropeza @ErikEJ

Comment: There was a missing coma at `COALESCE (res.kg, 0) as kg,  `

Comment: well, its coming closer I guess! this time I got this error! `There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 5,Token line offset = 7,Token in error = VALUES ]`, Im sorry for my inability to troubleshoot this myself but this for me kind of advanced SQL stuff is beyond my expertise! @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: Remember I'm doing this in my head. Check [**HERE**](http://rextester.com/MUX70196) Put your table with some data and send me the link so I can verify the query syntax.

Comment: I guess you are testing direct on sql server? You can try remove parts until you find where is the error. I double check and couldn't found the error.

Comment: I just did a foreach and tried to display kg! But I updated my post with a picture of my database. There is no 0 or null value in my database, lets say for an exercise (exerVariName), for example frontsquat, which appears 3 times in the picture, has a rep value of 8, 6 and 5, and then also a kilogram value to it, could be multiple rows with same rep value, but in that case, select the one with highest kilo, however, in this case its only 3 results, I want to write out 12, so for the rest of the rep values from 1-12, I want to output a 0 except for in this case on 8, 6 and 5! @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: Also now included one more pic, that displays how I want if almost, so as you can see I have 1-12 as a table header, and would want the top kilogram value of each exercise to be under each rep value that is represented by the table header, so I want to fill the blanks with a 0 to make the whole table appear! @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: Did you saw the link to [rextester](http://rextester.com/MUX70196)?  Upload your data there so I can test it.